# Anyone have an experience to integrate Avatara AvaTax in stripe invoicing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, avalara

I have to `integrate Avalara AvaTax for stripe invoice`. I have `Ruby on Rails` development project where already integrated Stripe.

Now, as per client request, I have to integrate AvaTax with stripe which calculate Tax based on charges.

I have this link

> https://help.avalara.com/FYHP/AvaTax_for_Stripe_Invoicing/Install_and_Configure_Avalara_AvaTax_for_Stripe_Invoicing

But, still not have some clear flow for it.

Anyone have an experience which would be great help for us.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you sucessfully integrated it? I'm currently starting on it and would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, integrated successfully it.